# Firefox doesn't $_POST all repeating region values, it only posts the last one

Tags: php, html, firefox

So the code posted below work fine in Internet Explorer but not in Firefox.  When passing the URL variable `UserName` Firefox only uses the last record in the record-set regardless of which button is chosen.  This page uses a repeating region in order to allow a site administrator to set passwords, update user profiles, and delete users by clicking on individual buttons within each region.  What should happen is that when a button is clicked it should forward you to the corresponding page with that regions `UserName` value included on the end of the URL.  The issue is within Firefox only. `$_POST['UserName']` always equals the value of the last created record in the SQL database.  I am pretty new to PHP so I am not sure what I am overlooking here. None of my searches have been any help.

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
$query_ManageUsers =$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserLevel = 0 ORDER BY UserName ASC");
$query_ManageUsers->execute();
$row_ManageUsers = $query_ManageUsers->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$query_RowCount = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users");
$totalRows_ManageUsers = $query_RowCount->fetchColumn();

if ((isset($_POST['UserID'])) && ($_POST['UserID'] != ""))
{
    $userName = $_POST['UserName'];
    switch ($_REQUEST['admin'])
    {
        case "Reset Password":
            $redirect = "SetPassword.php?UserName=$userName";
            header(sprintf("Location: %s", $redirect));break;
        case "Update Profile":
            $redirect = "UpdateUserProfile.php?UserName=$userName";
            header(sprintf("Location: %s", $redirect));break;
        case "Delete User":
            $redirect = "ConfirmDelete.php?UserName=$userName";
            header(sprintf("Location: %s", $redirect));break;
    }
}
?>
```

And here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html: charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Admin</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">document.documentElement.className="xr_bgh2";</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_htm_files/xr_main.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_htm_files/xr_text.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_htm_files/custom_styles.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index_htm_files/roe.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="xr_bgb2">
<div style="width:625px;">
<label style="text-align:left; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold;" >User Administration</label>
<?php if ($row_ManageUsers != 'null') { // Show if recordset not empty ?>
<?php do { ?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <form id="ManageUsers" method="post" >
        <table width="615">
        <tr>
        <td style="width:250px">
        <input name="UserName" style="width:250px; background-color:#C8DACA; border:none; font-size:14px" id="UserName" value="<?php echo $row_ManageUsers['UserName']; ?>" readonly="readonly" /></td>
         <td style="width:100px">
         <input name="admin" type="submit" value="Reset Password" form="ManageUsers" /></td>
         <td style="width:100px">
         <input name="admin" type="submit" value="Update Profile" form="ManageUsers" /></td>
         <td style="width:100px">
         <input name="UserID" type="hidden" id="UserID" form="ManageUsers" value="<?php echo $row_ManageUsers['UserID']; ?>" />
         <input name="admin" type="submit" value="Delete User" form="ManageUsers"/>
         </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
  </form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php } while ($row_ManageUsers = $query_ManageUsers->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); ?>
<?php } // Show if recordset not empty ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have the same `name` attribute on your `input` which is the reason why it's causing the issue. Might better solution in your case is to use `radio` button instead.

Comment: The problem is you are looping out your forms, and then your id's are all the same, some browsers ignore this others have fits if you don't have unique Ids, I suggest including something unique to each id.  Likely firefox is only submitting the last form no matter what button you click, because of this.

Comment: @Robin the only way I could get the [tag:switch] function to work was to have the names the same.

Comment: Those inputs with the same names are submit buttons, and don't matter as only one is used when submitting the form (much like a radio button ), the actual 'data' is in the hidden field and it's perfectly acceptable to have multiple submits with the same name and different values.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I showed the hidden ID field and each ID is unique within each form.

Comment: @JohnT  So this is unique?  <form id="ManageUsers" method="post" > - each forms ID has to be unique or the browser may see only one form or use the last, it's bad form ( pun intended )

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I was talking about the hidden `input` field.  I see what you are getting at.  I need to auto increment the id field of the form every time the form loops.

Comment: @JohnT - I know that is what you were talking about that is why I clarified my answer, let me know if it was the form ID, Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments the issue is that your form(s) have the same ID, if you look at your html/php code you will notice that the whole form is output for each loop, and that includes the same id for each iteration of the loop.

Some browsers will ignore this others may just use the last occurrence of the ID.

Without testing this I cant be 100% sure that is the issue, but it's bad practice at the least and should be fixed.

I would suggest using a unique id or even using that id as a class instead.

Just to clarify, when I said form id I mean this

```
 <form id="ManageUsers" method="post" >
```

Comment: @ ArtisiticPhoenix once I finally go the form name to increment that was it.  Thanks for all your help. All I did was initialize `$i = 1` and then set the form id to `id="ManageUsers<?php echo $i++ ?>"`.  I also removed the `form=` tags in all of the inputs.

Comment: Sure thing, it's an easy mistake that can be real hard to spot unless it's happened in the past, not saying I would ever do anything like that, lol